# Loading a layer in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Following is the code iam working

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>register',  
    data: "",    
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ldcontent").html(data);
    }
});
```

I want to call a layer in the above code as following in `#ldfgp`

```
$('#ldcontent').load('<?php echo site_url(); ?>register #ldfgp');
```

My Question is It is possible to call a layer (`#ldfgp`) from a loading page to my master page through `$.ajax()`.

I cannot use load function in jquery because it excludes the JavaScript embedded in the loading page.

Your suggestions and helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: Whoa, [*layer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_element)? Netscape called, they'd be so happy to meet you

Comment: Do you mean you want to just grab the section with the ID #ldfgp from the register page?

Comment: @philPlease clear what your are trying to answer for my question ? could u pls explain ?

Comment: @Sacha Yes absolutely :)

Comment: Any possibility to do this from  theoutstanding experience of you people in jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may load the whole document to some HTML fragment and then fetch relevant content from it

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>register',  
    data: "",    
    success: function (data) {
        var $fragment = $('<div/>').html(data);
        $("#ldcontent").html( $fragment.find('#ldfgp').html() );
    }
});
```

Comment: @Vadmin It is working fine in IE and ...Zilla. According to your look up any issue in other browsers ?

Comment: @t0m I have tested it in Safari and Chrome on Mac as well, thus it should be no issue with this code.

Comment: Thanks Vadim once again for your kind advice

Answer (score 1):

due to $.ajax load entire html document include html>body,$(data) is creating a little odd Jquery object. 
so you can use $(data).find or $(data).filter to find your element. you can try some like:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',   
url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>register',  
data: "",    
success: function (data) {
     var $data=$(data);
     var $layer=$()
             .add($data.find('#ldfgp'))
             .add($data.filter('#ldfgp'));



      $('#ldcontent').html($layer);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',   
    url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>register',  
    data: "",    
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ldcontent").html(data);
        $("#ldcontent *").css('display','none');
        $("#ldcontent #ldfgp").css('display','block');
        $("#ldcontent #ldfgp *").css('display','block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. but failed ... :) Nothing is displaying

Comment: just add this line - $("#ldcontent #ldfgp *").css('display','block');

Answer (score 0):

So, let's assume we have the `register.html` document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ldfgp">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello 3</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using $.ajax() you could grab the element with id `#ldfgp` this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: './register.html',
                data: "",
                success: function (data) {
                        var external = $.parseHTML(data);
                        $.each(external, function(i, e) {
                            if ($(e).attr("id") == "ldfgp") {
                                $("#ldcontent").html(e);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                }
        });
    });
```

But personally I'd prefer Vadim's solution, as it is cleaner and doesn't involve explicit .each() iteration.